# Submitting a SPARQL query with variable binding to GraphDB REST API

Tags: rest, sparql, graphdb

I am trying to submit a SPARQL query to a local repository on Ontotext GraphDB via its REST API. According to the documentation, one of the query params is also `$<varname>` which specifies variable bindings.

Suppose we have a repository called `testrepo` that contains customers, each of whom has a unique `customerID`. Submitting the following query:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/>
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?customer a :Customer ;
           :hasID ?customerID .
}
```

as a GET request with the respective variable binding `customerID = "123"` unfortunately retrieves all the customers and not the specific one.

Here is the request:

```
http://localhost:7200/repositories/testrepo?query=PREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%09%3Fcustomer%20a%20%3ACustomer%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3AhasID%20%3FcustomerID%20.%0A%7D%20&customerID="123"
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try with a leading `$` char to indicate that the HTTP param is a query variable?

Comment: *"one of the query params is also $<varname> which specifies variable bindings."* As @UninformedUser mentioned, you'd probably need `&$customerId="123"` for this to work.  Otherwise, it'd be impossible to bind a value for a variable called `query`, since `?query=...` is already used for the query itself.

Comment: Note that you could also use a `values` block within the query: `select ... where { ... values ?customerId { "123" } }`.

Comment: Duh, both of you are absolutely correct, I needed to add a `$` in front of the param name. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: As specified by [UninformedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser) and [Joshua Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor), I should have added a `$` in front of the param name.

The correct request is the following:

```
http://localhost:7200/repositories/testrepo?query=PREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%09%3Fcustomer%20a%20%3ACustomer%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3AhasID%20%3FcustomerID%20.%0A%7D%20&$customerID="123"
```